# Copy paste in transpose

Tags: vba, excel

I have few text in each column till `A1000` and each is separated by space. I want to copy and paste in transpose one below other

Original data I have for example

```
A  
AA
BB
CC
DD

PP
QQ
RR
SS
TT
```

What data needs to be in below format using Macro:

```
A AA BB CC DD
PP QQ RR SS TT
```

Please help me

Comment: Show the code you have written so far and somebody will point out how to improve it, make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the range areas:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim RangeArea As Range

    For Each RangeArea In Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Areas

        RangeArea.Copy
        Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

    Next RangeArea

    Application.CutCopyMode = 0

End Sub
```